# Regex to extract 2 lists of connected words

Tags: regex

I want to extract 2 lists of words that are connected by the sign `=`. The regex code works for separate lists but not in combination.

Example string: *bla word1="word2" blabla abc="xyz" bla bla*

One output shall contain the words directly left of =, i.e. *word1*, *abc* and the other output shall contain the words directly right of =, i.e. *word2*, *xyz* without quotes.

`\w+(?==\"(?:(?!\").)*\")`
extracts the words left of =, i.e. *word1,abc*

`=\"(?:(?!\").)*\"` extracts the words right of = including quotes and =, i.e. *="word2",="xyz"*

How can I combine these 2  queries to a single regex-expression that outputs 2 groups? Quotes and equal signs shall not be outputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
([^\s=]+)="([^"]*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3rX7O3/1/). *Details*:

- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 1: one or more occurrences of a char other than whitespace and `=` char
- `="` - a `="` substring
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `"` char
- `"` - a `"` char.

Note: `\w+` only matches one or more letters, digits and underscores, and won't match if the keys contain, say, hyphens. `(?:(?!\").)*` [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) is not efficient, and does not match line break chars. As the negative lookahead only contains a single char pattern (`\.`), it is more efficient to write it as a negated character class, `[^.]*`. It also matches line break chars. If you do not want that behavior, just add the `\r\n` into the negated character class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for lhs and rhs  from lhs="rhs" this should work (Sorry this what I understood from your question)

```
import re
test_str='abc="def" ghi'
ans=re.search("(\w+)=\"(\w+)\"",test_str)
print(ans.group(1))
print(ans.group(2))
my_list=list(ans.groups())
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

`(?: (\w*)=)(?:\"(\w*)\")`

This is for a python regex.

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/QN4q5R/2).